# Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'information_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'informacia'

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

What is the problem with these tables?

```
create table informacia
(
    adress_id int primary key,
    street varchar(20),
    city varchar(10),
    state varchar(2),
    zip_code int
);
```

I want to create foreign key for second one

```
create table information
(
    FirstName varchar(10) ,
    LastName varchar(15),
    AdressLine1 varchar(20),
    City varchar(10),
    StateProvinceCode varchar(2),
    PostalCode int,

    foreign key(PostalCode) 
         references informacia(zip_code) on delete set null
);
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and tag the DBMS you're using.

Comment: If you hover the `sql` tag it says to: `...and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used.`, so that any potential answers/suggestions match the DB that you use, so that it works, because there can be subtle differences for how it's done between DBs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for a table to add a foreign key constraint, the referenced column (`zip_code` in this case) must be a `PRIMARY KEY` or must have a `UNIQUE` constraint (ideally with `NOT NULL`).

I modified the SQL statements according to PostgreSQL database. You don't mention the specific database and PostgreSQL implements a highly standard SQL. The script, modified with two changes, is:

```
create table informacia(
    adress_id int primary key,
    street varchar(20),
    city varchar(10),
    state varchar(2),
    zip_code int not null, -- added NOT NULL
    constraint uq_zip_code unique (zip_code) -- added the UNIQUE constranit
);

create table information(
    FirstName varchar(10) ,
    LastName varchar(15),
    AdressLine1 varchar(20),
    City varchar(10),
    StateProvinceCode varchar(2),
    PostalCode int,
    foreign key(PostalCode) references informacia(zip_code) on delete set NULL
);
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kgf98AeGUb9LiLUboByL3F/0).